# Add two top borders to a table row with CSS

Tags: html, css, border, css-tables

How can I achieve a similar effect as in http://jsfiddle.net/eLWe3/2/, but without the additional markup?

I tried with `tr:before {}`, but it messes with the table. Solution has to work with IE8 and up, fallback to a single border on IE7 is okay.

Comment: I'd say the edit in my answer below is as close as you'll get. It only requires the addition of a class to the final table row for IE8 support.

Answer (score 2):

[This fork of your original example](http://jsfiddle.net/7Nvqm/) is as close as I could get. The updated CSS is:

```
table { margin: 0 auto; border-collapse:separate; }
thead { background: #FDECEE; }
th { font-weight: bold; }
tbody tr:last-child td { border-bottom: 1px solid blue; }
tfoot td { border-top: 1px solid pink; }
```

But, as you can see, I've not been able to get the 2px gap you wanted between the two borders. As far as I know, this won't be possible without additional markup of some description: hopefully I'm wrong.
​

**Edit** - I've created a [new example](http://jsfiddle.net/jG9yX/) that uses generated content to get the gap you're after:

```
tbody tr:last-child td:after {
    content:''; 
    display:block;
    border-bottom: 1px solid blue;
    margin-bottom:2px;
}​
```

It works in Firefox, Chrome and IE9+, falling back to a single border for less capable browsers. The only reason IE8 fails is because it lacks support for `last:child` to target the final row in the `tbody`. You could add a class to the last row in the table (either directly or using JavaScript) to get it working in that browser.

Answer (score 0):

not a great idea but use a background image on the relevant row/cell

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this is an acceptable alternative:

```
tbody {
    border-bottom: 2px outset pink;
}
```